# Probably that a submatrix of a unitary matrix has determinant $0$?

Tags: matrices, determinant, unitary-matrices

Suppose I have a (Haar-random) $m\times m$ unitary matrix $T$, i.e. $TT^\dagger=\mathbb{I}$.  Now I take a submatrix from this by taking a subset $(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n)$ of $n<m $ rows and a possibly different subset $(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)$ of $n<m$ columns (not a principal submatrix).

Call the resulting $n\times n$ submatrix $U$.  What is the probability that $\hbox{det}(U)=0?$  I suspect basically $0$ but I wouldn't know how to prove this.

Comment: Are you sure that the answer doesn't depend from the starting matrix $T$?

Comment: If you take $m=2$ $n=1$, if $T$ is identity matrix your probability is $\frac 12$, if you take a rotation matrix it can be 0.

Comment: @AlessandroCigna  No I am not.  All I know is that I have to draw a Haar-random unitary and work with a submatrix that is not principal.  I realize there are submatrices for which it is not possible to have Det=0, and some for which Det=0 by pure luck, but my intuition does not go beyond this.

Comment: Ok, but maybe if you tell where the problem come from we can reason about another way to solve, since this way takes us to a problem not well defined

Comment: @AlessandroCigna such submatrices occur for instance in BosonSampling (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson_sampling)

Comment: The fact that the set of matrices with this property is the solution set to polynomials over the entries of $T$ (i.e. is Zariski closed) is enough to deduce that the probability must be zero.